# Free dns with wildcard subdomains?

Tags: dns, subdomain, dyndns

Are there any free dns services i can use to access my local host over external ip that support wildcard domains?  This way i can set up virtual hosts to serve the subdomain content based on subdomain name.

For example, suppose the free fqdn with dns service is:

example.com

```
Example.com - my server root, default vhost
Site1.example.com - loads site1 vhost
Site2.example.com - loads site2 vhost
*.example.com - i can create a vhost for whatever the wildcard value is and it'll work like the two above
```

I don't mind if the free fqdn is a top level domain.    Example.aa.bb.cc is fine as long as i can set up *.example.aa.bb.cc

A free  fqdn/dns without support for wildcard subdomains but has lots of free subdomains i could set up would be OK, but not preferred.

Also, dynamic dns is not a requirement.   My external ip very rarely changes so i wouldn't mind updating it if it ever changes.

I know I'm asking for a lot for free.   I don't mind buying a domain name but I'm trying to get away with free if i can.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to build your own domain server to handle the subdomain information, for example using Bind software. After that you need to submit your NS record to your domain register

Answer (score 0):

Found a good one.   dtdns.com is free and allows for wildcard subdomains for free.

Comment: Service is now closed